# Getting changes in properties file without building web application repeatedly

Tags: java, web-applications, war, properties-file

I created a web app and in a seperate folder that I already added to classpath I have a properties file. I'm getting the property object using

```
public static Properties getProps()  {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mdmdemo.properties"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BasicUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

No problem getting the keys. However, although I placed the property file outside of the war, I cannot see changes done in prop file before building and deploying the war. I'm also creating new property objects repeatedly to see the changes, not just in the web app initialization.

I know, using database is a better solution in this case but I'm not allowed to do that.

How can I get the changes?

Comment: If `getProps()` is only called when the war is deployed, you will never notice a change in the properties file. You need to set up a Watch Service on the directory containing the file. Check out [Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: I'm calling getProp() in the doGet() function of the servlet. The page itself is refreshing periodically. I think that should be enough, am I wrong?

Comment: Sounds like it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Caching is probably CassLoader specific. If you use tomcat, this could help:

```html
ClassLoader ctxLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resURL = ctxLoader.getResource(resName);
URLConnection resConn = resURL.openConnection();
resConn.setUseCaches(false);
InputStream resIn = resConn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Nah, that also doesn't work. Although I'm using jboss, I tried but no way.

Answer (score 0):

Although I also suspected on caching issue https://stackoverflow.com/users/4763733/fran-montero told, I overcame the problem using

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream("/absolute/path/to/filename.properties");
```

Not using ClassLoader solved the problem.